# Will .htaccess files still work if Nginx is running (along with Apache)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Will .htaccess files still work if Nginx is running (along with Apache), or do I need to disable Nginx for them to work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you run both web servers without changing the default port, they will conflict and one of it will not start(most likely the 2nd one you start up). Those are 2 different web servers and behave differently, the rewrite rules in nginx work differently than on apache. If you're not using apache then you will have to create the suitable rules using ngnix format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is an Apache config file.  Nginx doesn't use it (file is ignored and treated like any other), and Apache config rules don't apply to Nginx.